# c style string on c++ question

Tags: c++, string, types, char

so you can do c style string on c++ using char * ...

my question is, can you pretty much do anything you can do on normal string with such declaration..

so suppose you have

```
char * c;
```

can you do:

```
c = "etcetc";
c = c + "dddddd";
```

etc?

and moreover is it pretty much interchangable with string?

so

```
char * c = "etcetc";
string s; 

s = c;
```

would that be valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C-style string is essentially a NULL terminated character array while std::string in C++ is an well-designed object-oriented string class/object. **In most case, they're NOT interchangeable** and it depends on what operation you perform. You can always call `std::string::c_str()` to get the internal C-style string.

```
char * c

// OK because this makes c point to the starting address of "etcetc",
c = "etcetc";

// Compile-time error! You cannot add two pointers anyway because it's meaningless
c = c + "dddddd";

// OK, because string has constructor "string ( const char * s )"
string s1 = c;

string s2;
// OK, because string has "string& operator= ( const char* s )"
s2 = c;
```

One thing worth mentioning:

```
// "etcetc" is a constant string here and you cannot modify it via pointer c
char * c = "etcetc";

// You can change string contents in two cases
char c[] = "etcetc";
string str = "etcetc";
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't concatenate `char*`s together using `+`; you have to use `strcat` and manually allocated buffers. That's why the `std::string` class exists in C++.

The assignment from `char*` to `string` *is* valid because the `string` class explicitly supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not, no.

(char *) is strictly a pointer to a memory location. String concatenation requires a new buffer with a copy of the source string (see strcat in your libC docs, for one method).

Answer (score 0):

`char*` is a pointer to (address of) a `char`. When you say `c = c + "xxx"`, you are adding the address of one string to another. This is almost certainly not what you want.

You'll need to use a string class that support concatenation to use the syntax you present. Otherwise, you can call old-style string functions like `strcat()`.

Comment: *"you are adding the address of one string to another"* - really?  I thought that wouldn't even compile (can't say I've ever tried it..)

Comment: I didn't try it either, but it should compile. Both expressions result in a `char*`, and C++ definitely support pointer addition/subtraction.

Comment: You can add integers to pointers, but you cannot add two pointers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935038/2935044#2935044

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched to C++ after years in Ada and C. I find I never use C style strings, except convert them to a string (and maybe back again if I have no choice). Do that, and a whole raft of common C problems disappears.

i.e. why `char * x="dadada";`when 
`string x="dadada";` is much easier later in the code?

This is valid code and doed exactly what you expect because c is a string, not a char*.

```
string c ;
```

.......

```
c = "etcetc";
c = c + "dddddd";
```