# Correct pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to learn pointer manipulation in C, and I am not understanding how part of the code isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int *alpha[17];

  *(alpha+4)= 35;
  *(alpha+5)= 35;
  *(alpha+12)= 50;

  printf("%d", *(alpha+4));
  *(alpha+8)=*(alpha+5) + *(alpha+12);

  return 0;
}
```

Why is the line after the `printf` not working, and causing a crash, when the previous lines ran perfectly?  I am trying to get the 9th value to equal the sum of the 6th and 13th value.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me. `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int *')`

Comment: You're adding pointers. You shouldn't be able to add pointers.

Comment: There's a couple different instances of undefined behavior in your code. When printf conversion specifiers don't match the argument type: `%d` when the argument type is `int*`. As well as assigning an int to a `int*`.

Comment: Don't ignore compiler errors/warnings

Comment: @Cornstalks OP is not adding pointer, but adding dereferenced values.

Comment: @MohitJain: the type of `*alpha` is `int*`, which is a pointer. OP is adding pointers. `alpha` is `int*[17]`, which decays to `int**`, so it's basically a double pointer. To add proper values, OP needs to dereference *twice*. Look at the error remyabel mentions: it involves adding pointers...

Comment: @Cornstalks Yes, you are right. Missed the declaration and assumed widely used `int alpha[17];` Pointer + pointer, does it even compile?

Comment: @MohitJain: It should not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int *alpha[17];` creates array of pointers.

If you want array of int, use `int alpha[17];`

Your assignations are succesful because of implicit cast from int to pointer. (I hope you are getting warnings)

Adding two pointers is not only non-sensical, but also not allowed in `C`.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935038/why-cant-i-add-pointers) covers why adding two pointers is forbidden in C++, but arguiments are applicable to C also.

Comment: Thanks, I misinterpreted the instruction of "Declare a pointer alpha of 17 components of type int.", and took it as creating an int array of pointers. I feel silly now, haha. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad you understood it.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array of pointers but have not array of `int`s.
You should use:

```
int alpha[17];
```

Comment: Note, though, that he isn't writing to the pointers. He's just writing to the array. -1 for the first sentence being misleading.

Comment: Try `int alpha[17] = { 0 };`.

Comment: @Cornstalks He's actually writing to a indirected array... a pointer to an array without an array allocated. He's writing to DEADBEEF.

Comment: @mr.stobbe: no, he isn't. For example, `*(alpha+4) = nullptr;` is totally fine in his code. As I said, **he's writing to the array, not the pointers**.

Comment: @Cornstalks note the `*` in `int *alpha[17];`

Comment: @mr.stobbe It's not a pointer to an array, it's an array of pointers. [http://cdecl.org/](http://cdecl.org/)

Comment: @mr.stobbe: I know it's an array of pointers. He isn't dereferencing the pointers; he's dereferencing the array.

Comment: I misinterpreted the instruction of "Declare a pointer alpha of 17 components of type int.", and took it as creating an int array of pointers. I felt that I absolutely had to leave it as an array of pointers, and find a way to do the aritmmetic that way. I feel silly now, haha. Thanks!

Comment: @Cornstalks Okay, wait... I'm honestly confused here, how is that not deadbeef on access? How am I wrong?

Comment: @mr.stobbe: `int *foo[2]; *foo = nullptr;` is legal for exactly the same reasons `int bar[2]; *bar = 0;` is. The array decays to a pointer, which is then dereferenced (so you're indexing into the array). [like this](http://ideone.com/RC28gy)

Comment: @Cornstalks But when did that mean that `*(foo + 0) = 0` not possibly result in a segfault?

Comment: @mr.stobbe: why would `*(foo + 0) = 0;` result in a segfault? That's exactly the same as `*foo = 0;`, which is the same as `*foo = NULL;`. Note that `*(bar + 0) = 0;` is totally legal too. Perhaps, though, you should open a new question and ask this, as we probably shouldn't use these comments for extended conversations.

Comment: @Cornstalks Silly me. That makes sense of course. It's late. That of course explains the crash at the assignment line. Silly me.