# Problem with templates, static inheritance. Can't get code done for a class Sorter whose members depend on type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a sortmethods class that inherits statically from different types of sort. Meaning that according to the type of sort choice, sortmethods inherit its members. I'm really new at working with templates.

I have tried using variadic templates, template of templates but I still can't fixed it.

```
template<typename SortMethod>
class Sorter : private SortMethod{
public:
    template<typename container, typename ... Types>
    void operator()(container cnt, Types ... args){
        this-> sort(cnt, args...);
    }
};

int main(){
    vector <int> v{10,1,20};
    Sorter<QuickSort> S1;
    S1(v,v.begin(),v.end());

    return 0;
}


class QuickSort{
public:
    template<typename C, typename forward>
    void sort(C cnt, forward primero, forward ultimo) {
        forward i, j, central;
        auto mid = (primero + ultimo)/2;
        auto pivot = *mid;
        i = primero;
        j = ultimo;
        do{
            while(*i < pivot) i++;
            while(*j > pivot) j--;

            if(i <= j){
                swap(*i,*j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }while(i <=j);

        if(primero < j){
            sort(cnt, primero, j);
        }
        if( i < ultimo){
            sort(cnt, i, ultimo);
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void swap(T x, T y) {
        T aux;
        aux = x;
        x = y;
        y = aux;
    }
};
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
/home/eduardo/Desktop/Utec/Poo2/Proyecto2/unidad-2-ordenamiento-Marcuss17/Sort.h:11:9:   required from ‘void Sorter<SortMethod>::operator()(container, Types ...) [with container = std::vector<int>; Types = {__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}; SortMethod = QuickSort]’
/home/eduardo/Desktop/Utec/Poo2/Proyecto2/unidad-2-ordenamiento-Marcuss17/main.cpp:14:27:   required from here
/home/eduardo/Desktop/Utec/Poo2/Proyecto2/unidad-2-ordenamiento-Marcuss17/Quick.h:12:29: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’)
         auto mid = (primero + ultimo)/2;
                    ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935038/why-cant-i-add-pointers

Comment: The parameter `cnt` (which, passed by value, is creating copies of the vector at every call) is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the compiler error message, it seems that `primero` and `ultimo` are of type `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Hence, `primero + ultimo` is not a valid operation.

I think you need to use

```
auto mid = primero + (std::distance(primero, ultimo) / 2);
```

instead of

```
auto mid = (primero + ultimo)/2;
```

Comment: I think `primero + (std::distance(primero, ultimo) / 2)` is meant